# How to reliably detect a barcode's 4 corners?

Tags: python, opencv, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

I'm trying to detect this [Code128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) barcode with Python + `zbar`  module:

[image]

(Image download link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgnHE.jpg)).

This works:

```
import cv2, numpy
import zbar
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
pil = Image.open("000.jpg").convert('L')
width, height = pil.size    
plt.imshow(pil); plt.show()
image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', pil.tobytes())
result = scanner.scan(image)

for symbol in image:
    print symbol.data, symbol.type, symbol.quality, symbol.location, symbol.count, symbol.orientation
```

but only one point is detected: `(596, 210)`.

If I apply a black and white thresholding:

```
pil = Image.open("000.jpg").convert('L')
pil = pil .point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1').convert('L')
```

it's better, and we have 3 points: (596, 210), (482, 211), (596, 212). But it adds one more difficulty (finding the optimal threshold - here 100 - automatically for every new image).

Still, we don't have the 4 corners of the barcode.

**Question: how to reliably find the 4 corners of a barcode on an image, with Python?** (and maybe OpenCV, or another library?)

Notes:

- It *is* possible, this is a great example (but sadly not open-source as mentioned in the comments):

  [Object detection, very fast and robust blurry 1D barcode detection for real-time applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM7cOo4R-fE)

  The corners detection seems to be excellent and very fast, **even if the barcode is only a small part of the whole image** (this is important for me).

  [image]
- Interesting solution: [Real-time barcode detection in video with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/15/real-time-barcode-detection-video-python-opencv/) but there are limitations of the method (see in the article: the barcode should be close up, etc.) that limit the potential use. Also I'm more looking for a ready-to-use library for this.
- Interesting solution 2: [Detecting Barcodes in Images with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/) but again, it does not seem like a production-ready solution, but more a research in progress. Indeed, I tried their code on this image but the detection does not yield successful result. It has to be noted that it doesn't take any spec of the barcode in consideration for the detection (the fact there's a [start/stop symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Start/stop_and_encoded_data), etc.)

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  image = cv2.imread("000.jpg")
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth = cv2.CV_32F, dx = 1, dy = 0, ksize = -1)
  gradY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth = cv2.CV_32F, dx = 0, dy = 1, ksize = -1)
  gradient = cv2.subtract(gradX, gradY)
  gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)
  blurred = cv2.blur(gradient, (9, 9))
  (_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 7))
  closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
  closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations = 4)
  closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations = 4)
  (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
  rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
  box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
  cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
  cv2.imshow("Image", image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  ```

Comment: There is an article on what you are asking here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/

Comment: @Ywapom I mentioned it in the question already.

Comment: Is your goal with this Question to find the barcode region, rotate it , and feed it to zbar? Do you expect the barcode to be a similar size in every image? How much variation do you expect in your images? I'm guessing a cut down version of the last code snippet could be made to work, but you might have to search more than one found rectangle to find the barcode.

Comment: The goal @bfris is 1) to read the barcode-encoded number with zbar, this works already all the time and is easy, but above all 2) use the corners of the paper sheet's top left barcode and bottom right barcode to perform a perspective correction

Comment: You want perspective correction on barcode(s) or the whole sheet of paper? If it is the whole sheet of paper, then you need 4 corners of the paper. The sample photo you provided does not have the whole sheet of paper and we cannot see the second barcode.

Comment: Of the whole sheet of paper @bfris. Top left corner of top left barcode + top right corner of top left barcode + bottom left corner of bottom right barcode + bottom right corner of bottom right barcode = 4 points and it's enough to do a perspective correction / homography (I tried it by manually enter the coordinates and it works).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution 2 is pretty good. The critical factor that made it fail on your image was the thresholding. If you drop the parameter `225` way down to `55`, you'll get much better results.

I've reworked the code, making some tweaks here and there. The original code is fine if you prefer. The [documentation for OpenCV is quite good](https://docs.opencv.org/master/), and there are very good [Python tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("barcode.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# equalize lighting
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
gray = clahe.apply(gray)

# edge enhancement
edge_enh = cv2.Laplacian(gray, ddepth = cv2.CV_8U, 
                         ksize = 3, scale = 1, delta = 0)
cv2.imshow("Edges", edge_enh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
retval = cv2.imwrite("edge_enh.jpg", edge_enh)

# bilateral blur, which keeps edges
blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(edge_enh, 13, 50, 50)

# use simple thresholding. adaptive thresholding might be more robust
(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 55, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Thresholded", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
retval = cv2.imwrite("thresh.jpg", thresh)

# do some morphology to isolate just the barcode blob
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 9))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations = 4)
closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations = 4)
cv2.imshow("After morphology", closed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
retval = cv2.imwrite("closed.jpg", closed)

# find contours left in the image
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
print(box)
cv2.imshow("found barcode", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
retval = cv2.imwrite("found.jpg", image)
```

edge.jpg
[image]

thresh.jpg
[image]

closed.jpg
[image]

found.jpg[image]

output from console:

```
[[596 249]
 [470 213]
 [482 172]
 [608 209]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A few remarks: 1) `If you drop the parameter 225 way down to 55`: is there a way to use the best thresh parameter automatically? Because the images have to be processed automatically without any manual thresholding slider parameter to set.

Comment: 2) The page will potentially contain a lot of text, and the morphology filter could also detect a big block of text with high density as a rectangle. So are there additional features that we can test to be sure it's a barcode (like distance between consecutive bars, or start/stop symbol) and not a block of text?

Comment: @Basj: the CLAHE equalization step is meant to make the lighting more uniform. But you could also use [adaptive thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). Regarding text, the morphology operations should thin the text way out. If remaining blobs are sufficiently larger or smaller, you can reject by size. You could also pass the rectangular parts to zbar to see if they're barcodes ( seems like this could be expensive). You may also give [feature matching and homography](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) a try.

Comment: How can this method be apply to real time video capture? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078167/how-to-reliably-detect-a-barcodes-4-corners-in-real-time-video-capture

Answer (score 2):

For the following to work, you need to have contrib package installed using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Your OpenCV version would now have a [separate class for detecting barcodes](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d25/tutorial_barcode_detect_and_decode.html).

`cv2.barcode_BarcodeDetector()` comes equipped with 3 in-built functions:

- `decode()`: returns decoded information and type
- `detect()`: returns the 4 corner points enclosing each detected barcode
- `detectAndDecode()`: returns all the above

Sample Image used is [from pyimagesearch blog](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/):

[image]

The 4 corners are captured in `points`.

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('barcode.jpg')

barcode_detector = cv2.barcode_BarcodeDetector()

# 'retval' is boolean mentioning whether barcode has been detected or not
retval, decoded_info, decoded_type, points = barcode_detector.detectAndDecode(img)

# copy of original image
img2 = img.copy()

# proceed further only if at least one barcode is detected:
if retval:
    points = points.astype(np.int)
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        img2 = cv2.drawContours(img2,[point],0,(0, 255, 0),2)

        # uncomment the following to print decoded information
        #x1, y1 = point[1]
        #y1 = y1 - 10
        #cv2.putText(img2, decoded_info[i], (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 3, 2)
```

**Result:**

Detected barcode:

[image]

Detected barcode and information:

[image]

Comment: For this to work you might have to have installed ```pip install opencv-contrib-python``` and not ```pip install opencv-python``` as the class is within the extra modules https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/

Answer (score 0):

One solution not discussed here is [PyZbar](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/).

It is helpful to know there are a number of different types of barcode so reading [this](https://barcode-labels.com/getting-started/barcodes/types/) can be helpful. Now each solution for decoding might have limitations for the types it can decode. @Jeru Luke's solution seems to be only support EAN-13 barcodes currently see docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d25/tutorial_barcode_detect_and_decode.html).

Now using PyZbar a simple solution for getting the rect object (4 corners) with the decoding and the bonus of finding out which type the barcode it is can be done with this script.

Using this [barcode](https://barcode1.co.uk/wp-content/assets/sites/18/ISSN2-1.jpg)

```py
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

file_path = r'c:\my_file'
img = cv2.imread(file_path)
detectedBarcodes = decode(img)
for barcode in detectedBarcodes:
    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)
    print(barcode.rect)
    print(barcode.data)
    print(barcode.type)
```

output

```
Rect(left=77, top=1, width=665, height=516)
b'9771234567003'
EAN13
```

Using @Jeru Luke's code you can `drawContours` and `putText`.

ZBar supports

- EAN-13/UPC-A,
- UPC-E,  EAN-8,
- Code 128,
- Code 93,
- Code 39,
- Codabar,
- Interleaved 2 of 5,
- QR Code
- SQ Code.

So I think PyZbar will also support these types.